# change selecteditem of dropdownlist after binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a droplist in page that i bind this with code

```
 Category catObj = new Category();
    dropCat.DataSource = catObj.GetAllCategory();
    dropCat.DataTextField = "Title";
    dropCat.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
    dropCat.DataBind();
```

i want change selected  item of droplist with ths code

```
dropCat.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(catObj.ParentId);
```

but this code cant change the selected item
please help me 
thank you all

Comment: Why can't that code change the selected item?  Is there an error message?  When you debug this, what happens after that line of code is run?  Is the `SelectedIndex` different?  Does something else set it back?

Comment: Do you mean to set the `SelectedIndex` or are you trying to set the `SelectedValue`?

Comment: no. this code run without error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that you're trying to select by value and not by index since `catObj.ParentId` is likely to contain a CategoryId. In case my assuption is correct, you'll need to do this

```
dropCat.SelectedValue = catObj.ParentId.ToString();
```

[`DropDownList.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property refers to a position inside Items collection and not about the value of the item.